# How can I make this callback change dynamically for local, staging and production?

Tags: node.js, staging

This function works well in my local.

However, if I want to make it work on staging, I need to change the callbackURL to: "https://staging-jobdirecto.herokuapp.com/facebook/callback" and then commit to staging.

And for production: "https://jobdirecto.herokuapp.com/facebook/callback".

Is there any way that I can make change dynamically (without me frequently changing this piece of the code)?

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: 1227008554140703,
        clientSecret: fbSecret,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback"

    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        return database.findOrCreateFacebookUser(profile.id, profile.displayName).then((user) => {
            done(null, user)
        })
    }
));
```

Af for production, I thought it could be done with something like this, but I wouldn't be sure on how to apply this to the staging environment:

```
if (process.env.CALLBACK !== undefined) {
    callback = process.env.CALLBACK
} else if () {
    callback = "http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback"
}
```

Thanks for your help,
Wilfredo

Comment: What about always reading it from the environment variable and never hardcoding it?

Comment: You can also implement a dynamic configuration logic to pick the right configs based on the environment as it is explained here
https://codeburst.io/node-js-best-practices-smarter-ways-to-manage-config-files-and-variables-893eef56cbef

Comment: Are you hosting staging and production on Heroku ?

Comment: yes i am hosting both on heroku

Answer (score 0):

You are using Heroku so you don't need if else checks because you can give different variables to environment parameters in different servers. What I mean is that you can change the code like,

```js
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: 1227008554140703,
        clientSecret: fbSecret,
        callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL

    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        return database.findOrCreateFacebookUser(profile.id, profile.displayName).then((user) => {
            done(null, user)
        })
    }
));
```

and **give config parameter named CALLBACK_URL** from Heroku Config Vars

[image]

Node will have access to that CALLBACK_URL parameter that you give from Config Vars.

Also when you are working in local since you don't have config vars coming from heroku, you can create an .env file in the root of the project and give the same parameter as

**.env**

```
CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback
```

Comment: @marcus did you try?

Comment: I tried just now. I worked well for staging and production. It didn't work for local though. I create a file called ".env" in my root folder and copyed and pasted exactly this line "CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback" but it doesn't seem to read it.

Comment: Hmm, can you console log process.env.CALLBACK_URL? It should read it via dotenv module

Comment: In the end I used an if statement that worked. Thanks for the help though!